# query for last devices documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb that store historical data for IoT devices. The documents on mongo db are like this:

```
  "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c5f97b9fd01ff005ab5a101"
    },
    "temperature": -1,
    "datetime": 1549768633858,
    "deviceId": 4085799
}

    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c5f97b9fd01ff005ab5a102"
    },
    "temperature": -27,
    "datetime": 1549768633863,
    "deviceId": 4085587
}
```

I want to find the last document for each device. I am using the following query

```
db.getCollection("sensors").find(
    { 
        "deviceId" : {
            "$in" : [
                4085799, 
                4085587
            ]
        }
    }
)
).limit(2);
```

It returns only two documents as expected but if one of the devices doesn't exist on the database i got duplicated results for the device that was found.
For exmaple if 4085799 does not exist i got

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c75b5a3f8d4d0005d90e1bf"), 
    "temperature" : NumberInt(-27), 
    "datetime" : 1551218083021.0, 
    "deviceId" : NumberInt(4085587)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c75b21ff8d4d0005d90e1b8"), 
    "temperature" : NumberInt(-27), 
    "datetime" : 1551217183157.0, 
    "deviceId" : NumberInt(4085587)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
```

How can i get only one result if the deviceId=4085799 is not on the database?

Comment: The first query doesn't return two results, given your documents

Comment: The sample documents was edited with the same deviceId.

Comment: It returns only 1 result when 4085799 is not in the collection. Maybe you run the same query twice?

Comment: @TechWisdom: note that in this case it returns different readings for the same device. Many readings per device.

Comment: OK now I got you. So you want only one document per each device? And why did you do: `.limit(2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Aggregation(mongoDB version 3.6 or above), you can find the last document for each device.

```
db.sensors.aggregate([
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$deviceId",
      id: { $first: "$_id" },
      temperature: { $first: "$temperature" },
      deviceId: { $first: "$deviceId" },
      datetime: { $first: "$datetime" }
    }
  }
])
```